# Listbox changes background color on selection

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-runtime, windows-store

On a windows store app project, i am using a listbox, that has a black background, when i click on one of the items on the listbox, my background changes to white.

i also tried to do the same on this sample 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Basic-Controls-29318599
and it happens here too, i changed the listbox background to red, and on selection of a item it changes to white again.

any idea what causes this and how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Using VisulStateManager you can achieve above requirements For more info go through [List Box Selected State handling](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Animating-ListBox-items-the-VisualStateManager.aspx) link

Comment: But is the scenario i explained normal? the ListBox returns to the default  background on selection change?

Comment: @Ric:Make listbox background to transparent and Make listbox parent (Grid)background to Red.